# Convert Bytes to MB with Decimal Point

Tags: android, decimalformat

How would I be able to convert bytes received from **TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()** to MB with a format to start like this 0.5 or 0.7 MB.

This a snippet of what I did:

```
        TextView txtData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtBytes);
        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX; 

        if(rxBytes>=1024){
            DecimalFormat formatKB = new DecimalFormat("0");
            double rxKb = rxBytes/1024;
            txtData.setText("0" + "." + formatKB.format(rxKb) + " KB");

            if(rxKb>=1024){
                DecimalFormat formatMB = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
                double rxMB = rxKb/1024;
                txtData.setText(formatMB.format(rxMB) + " MB");

                if(rxMB>=1024){
                    DecimalFormat formatGB = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
                    double rxGB = rxMB/1024;
                    txtData.setText(formatGB.format(rxGB) + " GB");
                }
            }
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: Could you explain what isn’t working? You’ve explained what you want and shown code but the problem isn’t clear yet. Please edit the question and clarify.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Hello sir sorry it wasn't explained clearly what I would want to achieve is that when I start getting the received bytes the output would be like this **0.0 MB** and then continously as **0.5 MB** and so on.